# Why is my spawn actor only working once when in a for loop? UE4

Tags: loops, game-engine, unreal-engine4, game-development, spawn

Im trying to set up when I go through a collision it checks how many current players there are then times them by 2, when I print out the math is correct however it only ever adds one to the actual count on screen, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
(My default player count in my game mode is 1.)

[image]

Comment: The problem may be in your UI blueprint. We'd need to see your UI blueprint. As shown, this code is correct.

Comment: I dont have any UI blueprint as of yet

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct that you spawn agents in the same location?
If so, you may want to mark `NoCollisionFail` input of the `SpawnAIFromClass` as **True**. Setting this value to **False** allows UE to abort the spawn in case if newly-spawned actor overlaps with anything solid (in your cast it may be previously spawned actor).

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: It kind of works with spawning the characters how ever I now get an error `Blueprint Runtime Error: "Accessed None". Blueprint:  Floor_BP Function:  Execute Ubergraph Floor BP Graph:  EventGraph Node:  Spawn AIFrom Class
Blueprint Runtime Error: "Accessed None trying to read property K2Node_DynamicCast_AsThird_Person_Character1". Blueprint:  Floor_BP Function:  Execute Ubergraph Floor BP Graph:  EventGraph Node:  Spawn AIFrom Class`

Comment: @KevinNisbet
That means that you are passing None to `getMesh` in one of the loop runs. That is probably because one of the newly spawned actors somehow deletes ThirdPersonCherecter. I'd recommend checking construction script of an actor you spawn to make sure it does not accidentally deletes main character or writing spawn location to the variable before entering the loop (so it will be calculated using valid ThirdPersonCharacter) and using it to spawn actors instead of recalculating spawn location with invalid character.